# Cassandra cannot start due to restricted column

Tags: cassandra

So I have an issue when I try to start Cassandra, I get the following error.

```
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.SyntaxException: line 1:32 no viable alternative at input 'primary' (... id, name, path, [primary]...)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.ErrorCollector.throwFirstSyntaxError(ErrorCollector.java:101) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.CQLFragmentParser.parseAnyUnhandled(CQLFragmentParser.java:80) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.parseStatement(QueryProcessor.java:526) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchView(SchemaKeyspace.java:1118) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchViews(SchemaKeyspace.java:1082) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspace(SchemaKeyspace.java:893) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchKeyspacesWithout(SchemaKeyspace.java:869) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.fetchNonSystemKeyspaces(SchemaKeyspace.java:857) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:136) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.Schema.loadFromDisk(Schema.java:126) ~[apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:247) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:581) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:710) [apache-cassandra-3.6.jar:3.6]
```

I guess, the issue is because I'm using column name `primary`, and it is not wrapped in single quotes. Is there any fast way to fix this, besides deleting the data folder of the Cassandra? All of my nodes are down, and I cannot start any of them.

Comment: Please show some code - [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jowey there is no related code. I have setup cassandra, but it's not starting. I have also provided information about the table and I know which field is causing the problem. I'm just asking if there is any faster way beside deleting the data folder of the cassandra.

Comment: You could show some parts of your configuration or at least describe the steps you took so far. At the moment it is hard for others to help you, since they only could guess what might be the problem.  
Just saying, because I wanted to help to improve the question.

Comment: Please try to use latest released version - 3.11.x instead of using 3.6 that is quite old...